# MAX or ALL in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing this question:

Which countries have a GDP greater than every country in Europe? [Give the name only.] (Some countries may have NULL gdp values)

The suggested answer from the website is:

```
SELECT name 
FROM world 
WHERE GDP >= ALL(SELECT GDP
                   FROM world
                  WHERE population>0 AND continent = 'Europe' )
```

Here it uses `ALL` keyword , and need to take care of the null value using `WHERE population >0`

My solution is like this:

```
SELECT name 
FROM world 
WHERE GDP >= (SELECT MAX(GDP)
                FROM world
                WHERE continent = 'Europe')
```

I use the `MAX` keyword and it seems that in this case we don't need to considering taking care of `NULL` value

Is my solution right? What's the trade-off of the two solutions?

Comment: GDP or population? Europe or world?

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Sqlite? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, just edited!

Comment: What's the expected result of one European country has a NULL gdp?

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate functions like `MAX` ignore `NULL`-values, so the meaning of condition

```
... WHERE GDP >= (SELECT MAX(GDP) FROM world WHERE continent = 'Europe')
```

is: it is true, if `GDP` is greater or equal than the GDP of every european country that has a `GDP` defined.

And it is equivalent to a condition like:

```
GDP >= ALL(SELECT GDP FROM world WHERE continent = 'Europe' and GDP is not null)
```

So it this is what you want to achieve (and I would interpret the exercise that way), then your approach is correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very small content available regarding the performance of both. The page is available [at MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-subqueries.html).

> - MySQL rewrites `IN`, `ALL`, `ANY`, and `SOME` subqueries in an attempt to take advantage of the possibility that the select-list
>     columns in the subquery are indexed.
> - MySQL enhances expressions of the following form with an expression involving `MIN()` or `MAX()`, unless `NULL` values or empty sets are
>     involved:
>
>   ```
>   value {ALL|ANY|SOME} {> | < | >= | <=} (uncorrelated subquery)
>   ```
>
>   For example, this `WHERE` clause:
>
>   ```
>   WHERE 5 > ALL (SELECT x FROM t)
>   ```
>
>   might be treated by the optimizer like this:
>
>   ```
>   WHERE 5 > (SELECT MAX(x) FROM t)
>   ```

Therefore; for your particular case, the website mentions using `ALL` because of the possible `NULL` values in data. If that were not the case, you can replace `ALL` with `MAX` as stated above.